# How to save a picture from picturebox control as a jpeg

Tags: c#, jpeg, picturebox

I have a picturebox on C# Windows Forms application. I want save image from picturesbox to file.

Does anyone have any idea how can I do it?

I newbie in programing...

Comment: pictureBox1.Image.Save("c:\\test.png");

Comment: You can do a ScreenCapture but you will have to add some effort to find the right area..

Answer (score 2):

```
pictureBox.Image.Save(@"SomePath",ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Buth I don't have a application source, I use compiled application.

Comment: Down vote was a speed mistake. Sorry for that. :) With the comment I just wanted to point out that you should mention the original source so the original answer gets the deserved credit. :)

Comment: @eg16 no worries, done that myself  :)  I had flagged the question as a duplicate